# Download file from ftp server in metro application

Tags: c#, ftp, microsoft-metro

In Metro application, I want to download files from a ftp server to local.

I tried to use Windows.Networking.BackgroundTransfer namespace and used the code:
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(ftpsource, destinationFile);

But the method download.GetResponseInformation() always returns null.

How could I work with ftp server in metro app?

Any experts of metro app answer this completely?

Comment: Sorry David, but in WinRT there is no namespace like FptResponse or FptWebRequest. Can any one help???

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with the new WinRT stuff - but from what I can tell the classes in the BackgroundTransfer namespace are for web-services and HTTP transfers, not FTP.

Can you reference System.Net.FtpWebRequest / FtpWebResponse?